# Access violation at adress

Tags: delphi, pascal, vcl

Реализую вращение фигур (прямоугольник, параллелограмм и шестиугольник) с использованием полиморфизма в VCL, использую переход от начальной формы к следующей, с самими фигурами. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: каскадом вылезают следующие ошибки:

[image: access violation]

Узнать, на какой строке это возникает нельзя, не показывает. Но если как-нибудь быстро перейти от первой форме ко второй и запустить движение фигур, то никаких ошибок не возникает, с чем это может быть связано?

Коды форм (кроме самой начальной, там ничего интересного) прилагаю:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, ComCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Image: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

uses unit4;

var
  t: single=0.0;
  H: THexagon;
  S: TSquare;
  P: TParall;
  Moving:Boolean=true;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  close;
end;




procedure TForm3.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  H:=THexagon.Create(250,250,50,Image);
  S:=TSquare.Create(475,250,50,Image);
  P:=Tparall.Create(700,175,900,275, 150,Image);
  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;

procedure TForm3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  H.Move(t);
  S.Move(-0.2*t);
  P.Move(0.5*t);
  t:=t+0.5;
end;


initialization

finalization
   H.Free;
   S.Free;
   P.Free;

end.
```

И форма с полиморфизмом:

```
Unit unit4;
Interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, ComCtrls, ExtCtrls;
Type
  TFigure=Class

    private
      x, y, halflen, dx, dy: integer;
      Image: TImage;
      procedure Draw; virtual; abstract;
      procedure Rel(t:real); virtual;

    public
      constructor Create(ax,ay,ah:integer;aImage:TImage);
      procedure Move(t:single);

    end;

    THexagon=Class(TFigure)
      private
        r: integer;
        procedure Draw; override;
      public
        constructor Create(ax, ay, ar: integer; aimage: timage);
    end;

    TSquare=Class(TFigure)
      private procedure Draw; override;
    end;

    TParall=Class(TFigure)
      private
        h:integer;
        x1, y1: integer;
        procedure Draw;override;
      public
        constructor Create(ax,ay, ax1, ay1, ah: integer; aImage:TImage );
    end;

Implementation

  Constructor TFigure.Create;
    Begin
       inherited Create;
       x := ax;
       y := ay;
       halflen := ah;
       Image := aImage;
    End;

  Procedure TFigure.Rel;
    Begin
       dx := 0;
       dy:=round(25*sin(t));
    End;

  Procedure TFigure.Move;
    Begin
       Image.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clWhite;
       Draw;
       Image.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clBlack;
       Rel(t);
       Draw;
    End;

    constructor THexagon.Create;
    begin
      inherited Create(ax,ay,ar,aImage);
      r := ar;
    end;

    procedure THexagon.Draw;
    var
      p:array[1..7] of TPoint;
      i:integer;
      a:real;
    begin
      a:=0;
      for i:=1 to 7 do begin
        p[i].X:=x+round(r*cos(a));
        p[i].Y:=y+dy-round(r*sin(a));
        a:=a+pi/3;
      end;
      p[7]:=p[1];
      with Image.Canvas do begin
          brush.Style:=bsClear;
          Polygon(p);
      end;
    end;

  Procedure TSquare.Draw;
    Begin
      image.Canvas.rectangle(180,100+dy,230,150+dy);
    End;

  Constructor TParall.Create;
    Begin
      inherited Create(ax, ay, ah, aImage);
      h := ah;
      x1:= ax1;
      y1:= ay1;
    End;

  Procedure TParall.Draw;
    Begin
      with image.Canvas do begin
        moveto(x, y + dy);
        lineto(x+h,y + dy);
        lineto(x1, y1 + dy);
        lineto(x1 - h, y1 + dy);
        lineto(x, y + dy);
      end;
    End;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас `Timer1` изначально `Enabled`. Поставьте ему в "Object Inspector"-е `Enabled` - `false`. Или перенесите

```
H:=THexagon.Create(250,250,50,Image);
S:=TSquare.Create(475,250,50,Image);
P:=Tparall.Create(700,175,900,275, 150,Image);
```

в `TForm3.FormCreate`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!